# Deleting Part of a Shape (Adobe Illustrator)

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to delete part of a dashed line in Illustrator (I marked the part that I want to remove with a red rectangle).

[image]

The Dashed line was created by an horizontal line tool with Zig-Zag effect, so the anchors are as seen here:

[image]

I've tried the eraser tool, mark a line and then use pathfinder, lasso tool to select the part I want to remove but none of them worked.

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: That appears to be a **raster** image. Is it? If it is, you can't edit a raster image with Illustrator. (Or perhaps you merely have Pixel Preview on?)

Comment: I just used screenshot - this is why the lower pixels. All of the lines were drawn inside Illustrator except the red rectangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **Pen Tool** to add an anchor point to the path where you want to cut it.

[image]

Then use the **Direct Selection Tool** to select the end anchor point:

[image]

Hit the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key:

[image]

There are other ways...

- You could use the **Scissors Tool** or **Knife tool** to cut the path,then delete the end section
- You could draw a new line and use **Pathfinder**, then delete the end section
- You can select the path *then* use the **Eraser Tool** to erase art of it.

All the methods essentially involve the same amount of clicks/keypresses so no one is better than another.

But with any of them, you *must* have the path *selected*.

---

Based upon Question update. An effect has been applied. Therefore, you must expand the effect... `Object > Expand Appearance...` or guess at where you want to cut the line and cut the actual path (the blue line), not the preview with the effect.

Comment: For some reason when I select the line I don't see the path, only horizontal blue line

Comment: Sorry, I can't really guess at what you are seeing.

Comment: I've edited the question

Comment: Do you have some **effect** applied to the path? That's the only reason I can think of which would cause such a selection preview.

Comment: Yes, it's an horizontal line with Zig Zag effect

Comment: You have to expand the effect... `Object > Expand Appearance`..  or *guess* at where you want to cut the line and cut the *actual* path  (the blue line), not the preview with the effect.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep the line without expanding, i mean the horizontal line with the zig zag effect, you can add a transparency mask to the line:

Select the line and click on "Make mask", uncheck "Clip" and select the mask area, the square at the right of the window.
[image: mask1]

Draw a 100% black shape on the area you want to hide, and click back the left square of the window to go back to the editing shape area of the file.
[image: mask 2]
And that's it
[image: Mask 3]

Answer (score 0):

Select the blue line and then Object>Expand, Object>Expand (yes, do it twice, the second time make sure "Fill and Stroke" are selected)

Select the line and then Right Click>Release Compound Path

Select the line and Ungroup

You may now delete individual dashes.

[image]